# Tkinter scrollbar no aparece

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

Estoy probando tkinter y al intentar insertar una scrollbar a una listbox de mi programa de prueba, la misma no se muestra. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```py
def boton_enviar():
    # Obtener dato
    var = n1.get()

    # Crear ventana
    ventana = w11

    # Cambiar estado de las ventanas
    w1.state(newstate='withdraw')
    ventana.state(newstate='normal')
    # Añadir titulo a la ventana
    ventana.title("Ventana 'w11'")

    # Colocar texto
    colocar_texto(ventana, texto=str("Resultados generados aleatoriamente y ordenados por codigo de publicacion."))

    # Añadir resultados
    resultados = generar_resultados(int(var))
    resultados = ordenar_por_codigo(resultados)

    # Crear elementosç
    '''Crea la lista'''
    listbox = Listbox(ventana)
    '''Crea la scrollbar'''
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(ventana)
    # scrollbar.grid()

    # Añadir listbox
    if len(resultados) < 10:
        caja = Listbox(ventana, height=len(resultados))
    else:
        caja = Listbox(ventana, height=25)

    for i in range(len(resultados)):
        caja.insert(END, resultados[i])
        caja.grid(row=1, column=1)

    # Configuración
    '''listbox'''
    listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    '''scrollbar'''
    scrollbar.config(command=caja.yview)
    # scrollbar.grid(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    # Boton atras
    Button(ventana, text='Volver al menú', command=botonatras).grid(row=2, column=1)
```

La idea es tomar el dato de un Entry que se encuentra en una ventana anterior y con ese dato al pulsar el botón 'enviar' crear una tabla que se mostrará en esta nueva ventana y que la scrollbar aparezca cuando el tamaño de la tabla supere determinado valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar el widget, debe llamar al método de ubicación (en este caso, `grid`). En su código, puede llamar a este método en la rama `else` de la condición.

```
if len(resultados) < 10:
    caja = Listbox(ventana, height=len(resultados))
else:
    caja = Listbox(ventana, height=25)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

caja.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')

for i in range(len(resultados)):
    caja.insert(END, resultados[i])
```

Tenga en cuenta que no necesita llamar a `caja.grid(row=1, column=1)` en un bucle, solo hágalo una vez.

El problema con `grid(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)` es que `grid` no tiene parámetros de `side` y `fill`, pero `pack` sí. Si usa `pack` en lugar de `grid`, entonces todo funcionará:

```
if len(resultados) < 10:
    caja = Listbox(ventana, height=len(resultados))
else:
    caja = Listbox(ventana, height=25)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

caja.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Puede encontrar más información sobre `pack` y `grid` aquí (en inglés):

- [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm)
- [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Al intentar implementar tu correción me tira el error "_tkinter.TclError: bad option '-side' etc..." haciendo alución a que el side=RIGHT que está dentro de grid no corresponde a los parametros permitidos de grid

Comment: @LeonardoSawka, arregle el código, intente ahora

Comment: Perfecto, ahora funciona correctamente, mil gracias. Podría por favor indicarme cual fue el error en un marco teórico?

Comment: @LeonardoSawka, complementé la respuesta.